# JQuery, don't hide element after post

Tags: jquery

How can I keep showing the form, even after I press submit?

```
<button class="show">Create Team</button>

<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="team_name" />

<input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
</form>
```

The Jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $(".show").click(function() {
        $("form").show();
        $(".show").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery isn't required in this case. You can just use plain javascript.

HTML (with inline CSS):

```
<button id="hide-show-button" onclick="hideshowform()">Create Team</button>
<form method="post" id="team-form" style="display:none;">
    <input type="text" name="team_name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Javascript (not JQuery):

```
var formstate = "shown";
function hideshowform() {
    if (formstate == "shown") {
        formstate = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("hide-show-button").innerHTML="Create Team"; 
        document.getElementById("team-form").style.display="none"; 
    } else {
        document.getElementById("hide-show-button").innerHTML="Hide Form"; 
        document.getElementById("team-form").style.display="block"; 
        formstate = "shown";
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want the ability to hide the form, use this code:

HTML (with inline css):

```
<button id="show-form-button" onclick="showform()">Create Team</button>
<form style="display:none;" method="post" id="team-form">
    <input type="text" name="team_name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Javascript (not Jquery):

```
function showform() {
    document.getElementById("team-form").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("show-form-button").style.display="none";
}
```